# New Domain Name - Staging Server

Tags: server-migration, staging-server, domain

My company is in the process of migrating a client's EE site from their old hosting company to ours. Prior to flipping the DNS switch and making everything live, we wanted to import the site to our servers and test it to confirm everything was working and unfortunately it's not. When we pull the site up on our site (which does have a new domain tied to it, since it's a temporary binding), we just get a blank white screen.

Our first thought is it's related to a licensing issue, as the "new" domain isn't licensed whereas our assumption is the old one is. We're fairly new to EE as an engine (mostly a Wordpress team) so am I on the right track here or is there something else we should look for?

Comment: Are all of the paths updated in the CMS? What steps did you take when moving the file over?

Comment: @MichaelMcGhee The paths are probably wrong, but we're not sure what to update here since nothing even comes up. This is our first exposure to EE so we're not really sure where to start.

Comment: When you get a white screen of death, turn on debugging in your index.php file. Look for "Error Reporting" and set `$debug = 1;`

Comment: Thanks! This set us in the right direction - turns out this version of EE is using a version of CodeIgniter that doesn't support PHP 7, because it's using `mysql_connect()` and not the mysqli set of libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is checking your config.php and database.php. They can be found in /system/expressionengine/config. Check your database credentials.

In the config.php file check the file paths and turn error reporting on.

Also, there might be an alternative config solution such as config bootstrap or master config. If that's the case, update those files with the proper settings.

Check the paths in your index.php and admin.php files in your root dir.

Check to see if you can log in to the EE cp

If you can log in, check and update all server paths

Also check this gist: https://gist.github.com/litzinger/5598641

If nothing helps, Contact us again ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Getting debugging turned on from above helped enough to get it running. Now that it is, we submitted a ticket to EE support for a separate issue, but otherwise we're good.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Whenever you need any more help feel free to shout!